# How to use an existing dummy variable to create a new one that takes the value 1 for certain lead observations within a group

Tags: r, group-by, conditional-statements, lag, dummy-variable

I have a dataset like the one below:

```
 dat <- data.frame (id  = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                  year = c(2015, 2016, 2017,2018, 2019, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019),
                  sp=c(1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0))
dat
   id year sp
1   1 2015  1
2   1 2016  0
3   1 2017  0
4   1 2018  0
5   1 2019  0
6   2 2015  0
7   2 2016  1
8   2 2017  0
9   2 2018  0
10  2 2019  0
```

I'd like to use the "sp" dummy variable to create a new dummy (call it "d") that takes the value of 1 for observations t+2 or more years (within each id group) after the sp variable takes the value of 1. The resulting dataset should look like the one below:

```
   id year sp d
1   1 2015  1 0
2   1 2016  0 0
3   1 2017  0 1
4   1 2018  0 1
5   1 2019  0 1
6   2 2015  0 0
7   2 2016  1 0
8   2 2017  0 0
9   2 2018  0 1
10  2 2019  0 1
```

Using the dplyr package, I am able to create the desired d variable for t+2 years after the sp variable takes the value of 1, but have no idea how to assign to d the value 1 for all years (within each id group) greater than t+2.

```
dat<- 
  dat%>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(d = dplyr::lag(sp, n = 2, order_by=year,default = 0))

dat

     id  year    sp     d
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  2015     1     0
 2     1  2016     0     0
 3     1  2017     0     1
 4     1  2018     0     0
 5     1  2019     0     0
 6     2  2015     0     0
 7     2  2016     1     0
 8     2  2017     0     0
 9     2  2018     0     1
10     2  2019     0     0
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cummax` on the `lag`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(d = cummax(lag(sp, 2, default = 0))) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
 A tibble: 10 × 4
      id  year    sp     d
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  2015     1     0
 2     1  2016     0     0
 3     1  2017     0     1
 4     1  2018     0     1
 5     1  2019     0     1
 6     2  2015     0     0
 7     2  2016     1     0
 8     2  2017     0     0
 9     2  2018     0     1
10     2  2019     0     1
```

Comment: Thank you, akrun. How should your code be modified if one wants to assign to d the value of 1 for t-2 or less years before the sp takes the value 1? Do we simply substitute "lag" with "lead". This change doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: @Teo perhaps you meant `mutate(d = rev(cummax(lag(rev(sp), 2, default = 0))))`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative using `cumsum` and an `ifelse` statement:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(id, col1 = cumsum(sp == 1)) %>% 
  mutate(d = ifelse(abs(first(year) - year) >= 2, 1, 0)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-col1)
```

```
  id  year    sp     d
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  2015     1     0
 2     1  2016     0     0
 3     1  2017     0     1
 4     1  2018     0     1
 5     1  2019     0     1
 6     2  2015     0     0
 7     2  2016     1     0
 8     2  2017     0     0
 9     2  2018     0     1
10     2  2019     0     1
```